# Open eclipse editor based on Editor Id

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

Is there any way I can get all the available editors not only the currently opened editors in the window .

Please help

Answer (score 1):

The editor registry has a number of APIs which will tell you about available editors.

Get the registry with:

```
IEditorRegistry registry = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getEditorRegistry();
```

You can find all the editors which can be used for a file with:

```
IEditorDescriptor[] editors = registry.getEditors("filename.ext");
```

Or you can find an editor with a given id:

```
IEditorDescriptor editor = registry.findEditor("editor id");
```

There is nothing that will list every editor known to the registry.

The `org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE` class also has a number of methods for getting editor descriptors and opening editors.

To open a file using a specific editor use:

```
IDE.openEditor(page, file, "editor id");
```

where `page` is the `IWorkbenchPage` and `file` is the `IFile` to open. This is equivalent to:

```
page.openEditor(new FileEditorInput(file), "editor id");
```

Comment: IEditorDescriptor editor = registry.findEditor("editor id"); this helped.Is there any way I can get the editorInput from this as I need to call  window.getActivePage().openEditor(editorInput, editorID,
       true);

Comment: The editor input is nothing to do with the editor descriptor or id. It is a description of the file or other input for the editor, for a file use `FileEditorInput`. See my edit for the easiest why to open a file using a specific editor.

Comment: I didn't want to export the whole plugin to the Util plugin .That is why i thought of finding the **editorInput** from the **Editor_id**.So I can reuse the same code in the framework everywhere. @greg-449

Comment: I repeat, the editor input is nothing to do with the editor id. It is the object (usually a workspace file) that the editor is going to edit. I don't know what you mean by that first sentence.

Comment: @greg-449 Could you please suggest is it possible to get concrete editor from IEditorDescriptor? For example, DiagramEditor.

Comment: @ElenaLarina You use the `openEditor` calls to open the editor, they return an `IEditorPart` which can be cast to the particular editor if necessary.